# Derive Turing Machine with high level description

Tags: turing-machines, normal-forms

So I have been going over Turing machines for my revision and came across an old worksheet with the question:

> Derive a Turing Machine using high level description with stages to decide on the following language {<,>|           }.

I thought I understood Turing machines and CNF until I came across this but I can't figure it out. There is no answer sheet for this so I was wondering could someone answer it with steps to guide me through it so I can understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy to check that $C$ is given in [Chomsky Normal Form](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Eauto191/wiki.files/9a.pdf), because you just have to iterate through the production rules and make sure each one of them satisfies the definitions for being a CNF production.

Then, the harder part is deciding whether $C$ can produce $s$ or not.
Notice, that a CNF will derive a word with length $n$, in exactly $2n-1$ steps. (every production will either transform a variable to the letter corresponding to it, or will create one new variable)
Keeping this in mind, we can just iterate through all production chains that contain $2n-1$ steps (for $n=|s|$), and check whether we saw $s$ or not. If $s\in L(C)$, then we will see it, since $s$ can be derived with $2n-1$ steps. And if $s\notin L(C)$ we won't see it, therefore the algorithm is correct.

Comment: You dont need to: "derive a turing machine using **high level description** [...]"

Comment: Glad that I can help!